# How to create notification dialog that can appear bottom of the screen in opencart portal

Tags: javascript, html, css, opencart, opencart-3

How to create notification dialog that can appear bottom of the screen in opencart ecommerce portal.
For example, please see the image below.
[image]

Thanks,
Noorul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a hidden button, by clicking it display the modal you need, and call it when you click on the image.